# RSpec Controller Test not generating right url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, rspec-rails

I am attempting to create a RSpec controller test for a namespaced controller, but rspec doesn't seem able to detect the nesting and generate the proper path for the `post :create` action.

This is my spec code:

```rb
# for: /app/controllers/admin/crm/report_adjustments_controller.rb
require 'spec_helper'
describe Admin::Crm::ReportAdjustmentsController do
  render_views

  before(:each) do
    signin
  end

  describe "GET 'index'" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get :index
      response.should be_success
    end
  end

  describe "POST 'create'" do
    it "creates with right parameters" do
      expect {
        post :create, report_adjustment: {distributor_id: @ole_distributor.id, amount: "30.0", date: Date.today }
      }.to change(Crm::ReportAdjustment, :count).by(1)
      response.should be_success
    end
  end
end

# routes.rb
namespace :admin do
  namespace :crm do
    resources :report_adjustments
  end
end
```

For this code, the `get :index` works just fine, but when `post :create` is called, the following error is generated: `undefined method 'crm_report_adjustment_url'`

Why would RSpec be smart enough to figure things out with `get :index`, but not with `post :create`? How do I get RSpec to properly load the right route, which is `admin_crm_report_adjustments_url`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: both `:get` and `:post` should be handled the same. have a look at `process` which handles the request stuff: http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActionController/TestCase/Behavior/process you could try to debug it in your application using pry, debugger or puts

Answer (score 1):

Try posting to the url instead:

```
post admin_crm_report_adjustments_url

# or 

post "/admin/crm/report_adjustments"
```